# Bin To Exe Requirements

Tags: exe, executable, bin

It seems as if there are several questions asking "How to make an exe" but there are no specific questions, that I can find anyway, asking what the requirements are for Windows to even consider running an exe file extension as a program. As to my knowledge, an exe is an executable, and a bin/img are both raw executables. When I change the file extension straight from bin to exe on Windows it throws an error about the file not being a proper executable, though it may be the fact that I tried my testing out on bootloaders and kernels coded in Assembly.

My main question is, does anyone know what kinda extra headers or information is needed to be added to an .asm file before compiling it into a .bin so that one could simply change the extension from .bin to .exe and see it working, or even better what this extra required information within a file is even called to make the answer to the question easier to obtain information on?

Comment: A header forming a structure which labeled as exe inside Windows probably gets loaded inside a runtime interpreter of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.iso is not an "executable", it is a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM file system image. .bin is just some arbitrary binary data. .img is generally an image of something. None of these are programs in any sense of the word. Also, Assembly is *not* executable, it is a mnemonic, human-readable translation of machine code, and will need to be assembled before it can be executed.

You can find information on the Portable Executable format here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format - Note that if you ever end up writing a PE header manually, you are likely doing it wrong.

In short: You can not just stick a file header to a .bin, .iso, .img or .asm file and have an executable. Sorry.

Comment: When a compiler take your .c source code and compiles to .asm and then assembler takes that source code from asm and makes it a .bin or .obj (Which I haven't had any luck assembling a .asm straight into an .exe, but am able to compile .asm to .obj and then turn the .obj into a .exe out of it. So I assume those are the steps any compiler takes when making .obj or .exe files is take .asm and make it into .obj first) but at this point there must be something being added to the code in which all compilers relate too, correct? Taking a look at your link now. Thanks for the time and insight.

Comment: Portable Executable is what this is called. Thank you!

Comment: The process of turning the .obj into a .exe is called "linking", it glues multiple objects together, resolves function references between them into jump instructions and adds the PE header (or ELF header if we're on Linux, or whatever).